# Why does `dd` use `=` in its parameters?

Tags: dd, history

Why does `dd` use parameters with a `=` (`if=/dev/zero`) and not the more common approach of something like `-i /dev/zero`?

I'm just curious if someone knows the historical reason or what the pros and cons are of this style.

Story time: When I've started to develop software I didn't knew what I was doing and used the `dd` style since it was easier for me to implement in a C# library. *(Like most developers I still don't know anything. Just how to use Google, StackOverlow and Copy&Paste.)*

Comment: Whoever voted to close this as opinion-based: it isn't, and neither are others like it. The circumstances surrounding the history of `dd` are real and unchanging historical facts, and if anyone were to be aware of them, this question could be answered with those facts. That history isn't up to the (current) opinions of anyone writing answers now, and anyone considering answering this should try to keep to facts, instead of personal opinions. That said, it's well possible that the actual answer to questions like this is just lost in history.

Comment: (I know, the text in the close reason says "likely to be _answered_ with opinions", but the actual history and historical design choices may be _interesting_. If we can get to them past all the after-the-fact guesses and dismissing the question as opinion-based.)

Comment: Related: [What does dd stand for?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/6804)

Comment: If we are lucky, a real oldtimer, who remembers why, might read this thread and tell us. Anyway, I remember using 'variable-name=some-string' in input *files* for some FORTRAN programs.

Answer (score 27):

[POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dd.html#tag_20_31_18) mentions the following in its rationale section for `dd`:

> Certainly, many of the operands could have been designed to use the Utility Syntax Guidelines, which would have resulted in the classic hyphenated option letters. In this version of this volume of POSIX.1-2017, *dd* retains its curious JCL-like syntax due to the large number of applications that depend on the historical implementation.

The reference to JCL echoes the description in [the Jargon File](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/D/dd.html) (the entry describes “dd” as a verb, but this reference is to the `dd` utility)¹:

> The Unix dd(1) was designed with a weird, distinctly non-Unixy keyword option syntax reminiscent of IBM System/360 JCL (which had an elaborate DD ‘Dataset Definition’ specification for I/O devices)

The late Dennis Ritchie [wrote that](https://groups.google.com/g/alt.folklore.computers/c/HAWoZ8g-xYk/m/HDUVxwTVLKAJ)

> dd was always named after JCL dd cards.

and that thread includes an example of a [JCL data definition](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos-basic-skills?topic=concepts-jcl-statements-what-does-dd-statement-do):

```
//JOB SMILEY
//EXEC CCLG
//SYSPARM DD DSN=USR.LOCAL.INCLUDE.STDIO,DISP=SHR
//SYSIN DD *
MAIN()
{
PRINTF("HELLO, WORLD\N");
}
/*
//
```

See also [this TUHS thread on dash options](https://www.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2017-November/thread.html#13672) where [Andrew Warkentin references JCL-style `key=value` options](https://www.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2017-November/013672.html).

As far as pros and cons are concerned, `dd` style options have one big advantage over typical dash style: all the program arguments are unambiguous. “Traditional” commands such as `rm` mix dash-prefixed options and file names; since file names can start with dashes too on Unix-style systems, this means that it isn’t always possible to decide whether a given argument is an option or a file. This can be worked around, but `dd` style options avoid the issue entirely. (For added fun, GNU `dd` supports non-`dd` style options, `--help` and `--version`.)

---

¹ The overall accuracy of this Jargon File entry [is disputed](https://www.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2019-October/019211.html), but the JCL connection isn’t.

Comment: Jargon File also needs a "[citation needed]" on that claim that it was a prank :) (It might be, there's just no evidence of that. It doesn't help that the File itself is/has been edited by "a number of individuals".)

Comment: +1, also for the Jargon File reference. (I host a mirror of the File and didn't even remember there was an entry for `dd`.)

Comment: @ilkkachu indeed, it’s probably best to drop that part of the quote since it’s not particularly useful.

Comment: @StephenKitt, welll. I do think it's an amusing quip. :) Just that it's too bad there's no date or name on that JF entry (or any others). Other than ESR's, that is. I wonder if I should go looking if there's a revision history of the JF somewhere...

Comment: @ilkkachu on the reliability of the Jargon File, I was amused by [this TUHS email](https://minnie.tuhs.org/pipermail/tuhs/2019-October/019211.html) ;-).

Comment: @ilkkachu mjg59 constructed a [Jargon File repository with history](https://github.com/mjg59/jargon) a while ago; see [the history of the `dd` entry](https://github.com/mjg59/jargon/commits/master/dd). The `dd` entry was added in ESR’s first revision (2.1.1).

Comment: @StephenKitt, hah, yes. Though if that `-if=` wasn't a typo or some Plan 9 custom, having a single dash with the equal sign looks like it would be a yet another new syntax (at least I don't think I've seen it anywhere else) so I wouldn't be surprised if it made someone irate. :)

Comment: @ilkkachu that's what openssl uses, e.g. `openssl x509 -in file.crt -text -noout`

Comment: I don't think I _ever_ saw such a small amount of JCL in one place… IIRC, most jobs had _pages_ of it!

Comment: @Edheldil, that's different, there's no `=` sign there. `-in file.crt` is similar enough to e.g. find's expressions like `-type f`, or xterm's `-geometry 120x60+123+456` (one dash, no equal sign), and e.g. GNU long options use `--foo=filename` (two dashes, optional equal sign). But the linked post had `-if=`, with one dash and an equal sign, and that's what looked very unfamiliar. Though, now that you mention OpenSSL, it does appear to accept `-in=file.crt` too! I've never seen anyone use it, though. :)

Comment: @StephenKitt, hmm, about that last addition, wouldn't the same apply for any program that didn't take any non-option arguments? Like if you had to use `rm -f somefile -f otherfile` to remove those two files, that would be unambiguous even for something like `rm -f -e -f foo`, which would remove `-e` and `foo`. (`-f` here 
being short for `--file-to-remove`, of course). With the `val=key` style, you still couldn't use `someprog ... *` as a filename could also contain an `=` sign.

Comment: @ilkkachu yes, I’m opposing strict `dd` style (where every argument is `key=value`, so file names containing `=` are still introduced by a `key=`) and traditional dash style where options and file names can be mixed, only.

Comment: yep. For unambiguous syntax, I guess one could make `--` or some other such separator mandatory. (Or start banning characters from filenames.) And then watch the complaints (in either case)...